# RegEx for maximum length with dot and replace function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, maxlength

How can I limit the length of a string with replace function.

I need to allow only stings like this pattern: 11.11, 99.99, 100.00

1-3 numbers before dot, one dot and 2 numbers after dot.

I have only something like this:

```
value = value.replace(/[^\d.]/, "");
```

Comment: you need to explain better what you are trying to do, your question is least ambiguous... try adding examples

Comment: You mean you want to reject/nullify all the strings that do *not* match that pattern?

Comment: Here is a pattern that will match your description: one to three digits followed by a dot, followed by two digits:  `/\d{1,3}\.\d{2}/`  Maybe this helps you find what you need.

Comment: MaxArt, yes, I must prevent to type in input more than 3 numbers without dot and type max one dot and max 2 numbers after dot.

Comment: @user7174627 So, does that mean that this check must happen *when the user is typing* or when the form is submitted/the field loses focus)?

Comment: MaxArt, I use this replace function on input: onChange

Answer (score 0):

Using alternation `|` operator to test both sides of the `.`:

```js
var str="11.11, 99.99, 100.00, 1333.05, 44.999"
console.log(str.replace(/([, ]*\d{4,}\.\d*|\d*\.\d{3,})[, ]*/g, ""));
```

**Explanation:**

- `[, ]*`: any number of `,` or space
- `\d{4,}\.\d*`: 4 or more digits followed by dot and any number of digits(match numbers with more than 4 digits before dot)
- `\d*\.\d{3,}`: any number of digits followed by dot and 3 or more digits(match numbers with more than 3 digits after dot)
- if one of the last two patterns are found followed by optional `,` or space, replace with empty string `""`